# Regex to replace the words alternatively

Tags: regex, alternation

I was working on the file names to give alternative names.
i.e. I have some duplicate or repetitive names.
This is the input:

```
 image  
 thisismyimage  
 image  
 image  
 anotherimage
```

I was looking for a solution to give alternative names to all these duplicate names.
`image` needs to be replaced with `imageofme`, `imageofher`, or `nextimage`
I'm expecting this output,

```
 imageofme  
 thisismyimage  
 imageofher  
 nextimage  
 anotherimage
```

I'm using simple regex, I tried to replace image with `[imageofme|imageofher|nextimage]`,  but it gives all images that name, anything placed in the replace with box was replaced with the entire `[imageofme|imageofher|nextimage]`.
Is there any solution to pick alternative names from it, or to get unique names to replace those duplicates (something like image number or id)?
Any ideas how alternation can be done in regex?

Comment: Any reason not to do that by hand? If you're looking for a programmatic solution, Notepad++ is not the right choice anyway.

Comment: No way, its too many names generated dynamically each week. Any programmatic solutions also appreciated,

Comment: @AlexMs: this cannot be done with regexes alone, you need to write some code. Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: @thg435 Yes, I do. But I don't think programming lang. can be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl:

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN { @alternative_names = qw(imageofme imageofher nextimage) }
    s/^image$/shift @alternative_names/e
' your_file
```

Scale as needed.